# Weird indentation behavior in C++ mode

Tags: indentation, c++

In C++ mode there is the following behavior of the indentation:

[image]

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not weird; `std:` could be a label and until you type the second `:` it doesn't know otherwise.

Edit: I forgot to mention, but you can customize `c-default-style` to choose a different indentation style, and you can add your own entries to `c-style-alist` to make one that's exactly to your liking.

Comment: As there is indentation of 4 spaces shouldn't everything - label or not - be placed in 4 spaces?

Comment: Labels aren't indented in any of the default indentation styles (see the `c-style-alist` variable) except the "java" style.